# How to generate all combinations using 5 columns using a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I saw and used the formula for combinations for 3 columns.  I have been trying to extend it to 4 columns and then to 5 columns.  I can't get it to work properly.  I don't want to use a table.
This was the original formula I found on this site posted by Scott Craner. I expanded on it for 5 columns but can't get it to work properly.

=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,IF(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*((COUNTA(C:C)-1)))))+2>COUNTA(A:A),-1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*((COUNTA(C:C)-1)))))+2))&" "&INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(C:C)-1)),(COUNTA(B:B)-1))+2)&" "&INDEX(C:C,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),(COUNTA(C:C)-1))+2),"")

Comment: It may be helpful to post the formula for the 3 columns (& 4?). Also it sounds as if you've tried hard getting it to work. What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: This was the original formula I found on this site posted by Scott Craner. 
 I expanded on it for 5 columns but can't get it to work properly. =IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,IF(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*((COUNTA(C:C)-1)))))+2>COUNTA(A:A),-1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*((COUNTA(C:C)-1)))))+2))&" "&INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(C:C)-1)),(COUNTA(B:B)-1))+2)&" "&INDEX(C:C,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),(COUNTA(C:C)-1))+2),"")

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extensible formula that can generate all combinations from an array input of up to five columns.

Caveats:

- It requires Excel 2019 or Excel 365
- It does not take columns as inputs - it takes an array, so you must size the input array to fit the columns that you want. (pls see notes below)
- While it does not rely on volatile functions, it is still computationally intensive and can run slow.
- You must have a minimum of 2 columns in your range and a maximum of 5.
- No column in the array can be completely blank.

In this example, I am taking an array of text cells in the range A1:E5 and I will combine them with a delimiter of " ".  The formula uses LET to make it more efficient and readable.  You can copy paste it into your destination cell - the formatting is only there to make it readable:

```
=LET( matrix, A1:E5,
      d, " ",
       cC, COLUMNS( matrix ), cSeq, SEQUENCE( 1, cC ),
       rC, ROWS( matrix ), rSeq, SEQUENCE( rC ),
       eC, rC ^ cC, eSeq, SEQUENCE( eC,,0 ),
       m, INDEX( matrix, MOD( INT( INT( SEQUENCE( eC, cC, 0 )/cC )/rC^SEQUENCE( 1, cC, cC-1, -1 ) ), rC ) + 1, cSeq ),
       n, INDEX( m, eSeq+1, cSeq ) <> 0,
       r, IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 1 ), "") &d& INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 2 ) &d& IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 3 ), "") &d&
           IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 4 ), "") &d& IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 5 ), ""),
       o, IFERROR( INDEX( r, eSeq+1, ), n ),
       FILTER( INDEX( o, , 1), INDEX( n, , 1 ) * INDEX( n, , 2 ) * IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 3 ), TRUE) *
               IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 4 ), TRUE) * IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 5 ), TRUE) ) )
```

Set the variable **matrix** to the range that you want.  It is currently set to A1:E5.  Set the **d** variable to the delimiter that you want to use.  It is set to " " or space right now.  Here is an example of the output:

[image: sample output]

**Notes**

I have another version that will take columns, but it is failing and I won't have time to debug it, so I thought it would be better to give you something for now that you might be able to adapt to your needs.  The other version is also computationally faster.  When I have debugged it, I will post it here.

This is extensible.  If you want it to go to 6, 7, or more columns, it can be pretty easily modified.  I chose not to do that because each column that it processes (even if there are no data in the column) slows down the calculation because of the design that I used. To extend it, you need to edit two lines near the end:

1. You have to edit the variable **r**. You need to append another `&d&IFERROR(INDEX(m,eSeq+1, XXX ),"")` **in front of the comma** where XXX is the next column. For example 6 and then 7, etc.
2. You have to edit the final result that starts with FILTER. You need to append another `*IFERROR(INDEX(n,, XXX ),TRUE)` **in front of the last two close parens** where XXX is the next column. For example 6 and then 7, etc.

Here is an example of a 7 column version:

```
=LET( matrix, A1:G5,
       d, " ",
       cC, COLUMNS( matrix ), cSeq, SEQUENCE( 1, cC ),
       rC, ROWS( matrix ), rSeq, SEQUENCE( rC ),
       eC, rC ^ cC, eSeq, SEQUENCE( eC,,0 ),
       m, INDEX( matrix, MOD( INT( INT( SEQUENCE( eC, cC, 0 )/cC )/rC^SEQUENCE( 1, cC, cC-1, -1 ) ), rC ) + 1, cSeq ),
       n, INDEX( m, eSeq+1, cSeq ) <> 0,
       r, IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 1 ), "") &d& INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 2 ) &d& IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 3 ), "") &d&
           IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 4 ), "") &d& IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 5 ), "") &d& IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 6 ), "") &d& IFERROR(INDEX( m, eSeq  + 1, 7 ), ""),
       o, IFERROR( INDEX( r, eSeq+1, ), n ),
       FILTER( INDEX( o, , 1), INDEX( n, , 1 ) * INDEX( n, , 2 ) * IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 3 ), TRUE) *
               IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 4 ), TRUE) * IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 5 ), TRUE) * IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 6 ), TRUE) * IFERROR(INDEX( n, , 7 ), TRUE) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I would love to see the other faster formula also.  This will get me done for now. This is a great forum I'm glad I stumbled on it.

Comment: @john-leonard  Sure - I am not sure when I will have time, but I will post it here and send you a comment. It works, but threw errors that I could not easily diagnose without burning a lot of time.  Let me know if this works for you and if it is truly slow.  In a small matrix, it was fast, but as soon as you go over 1000 results, it took seconds to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Say your data is in the first row for each column, you can use the following formulas to combine them. `&` `=Concat` `=Concatenate`

You can also add in custom text if you include `" "` in your formulas.

So you might use the formula like so:

`=A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 & E1` or you can do something like `=A1 & " " & B1` if you're trying to add a space between them.

Similarly, `=Concat(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)` / `=Concat(A1," ",B1)`

Lastly, `=Concatenate(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)` / `=Concatenate(A1," ",B1)`

Comment: Could you look at the formula above as this is exactly what I'm looking for but to expand it to 4 columns and then 5 columns. Thank you.